# Fast convolution algorithm have different outputs compared to regular convolution algorithm?

Tags: c++, optimization, conv-neural-network, openmp, convolution

I was trying to speed up a forward pass in a convolutional layer by using a technique of converting my image data to a column vector and essentially converting my convolution problem into a matrix multiplication problem.

[idea from https://sahnimanas.github.io/post/anatomy-of-a-high-performance-convolution/]

I did so by first implementing an im2col function from caffe's official github

```cpp
void im2col_cpu(float* data_im, const int channels,
    const int height, const int width, const int kernel_h, const int kernel_w,
    const int pad,const int stride,const int dilation,float* data_col) {
  int dil_kernel_h = (kernel_h - 1) * dilation + 1;
  int dil_kernel_w = (kernel_w - 1) * dilation + 1;
  int height_col = (height + 2 * pad - dil_kernel_h) / stride + 1;
  int width_col = (width + 2 * pad - dil_kernel_w) / stride + 1;
  int channels_col = channels * kernel_h * kernel_w;
  
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int c = 0; c < channels_col; ++c) {
    int w_offset = c % kernel_w;
    int h_offset = (c / kernel_w) % kernel_h;
    int c_im = c / kernel_h / kernel_w;

    const int hc0 = h_offset * dilation - pad;
    const int wc0 = w_offset * dilation - pad;
    for (int h = 0; h < height_col; ++h) {
      int h_pad = h * stride + hc0;

      const int row_offset = (c * height_col + h) * width_col;
      const int srow_offset = (c_im * height + h_pad) * width;


      for (int w = 0; w < width_col; ++w) {
        int w_pad = w * stride + wc0;
        if ((h_pad < height) && (w_pad < width))
          *(data_col + row_offset + w) = *(data_im + srow_offset + w_pad);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then multiplying the output with a custom matrix multiplication code.

```cpp
void mat_mul(float *A, float *B, float *C, int M, int N, int K, bool has_bias) {
  int i, j, k;

  if (!has_bias)  init(C, M, N); //init() converts C into a 0 matrix
  
  # pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k)
  for (i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    for (k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
      float * ptr_c = &C[i * N];
      float * ptr_b = &B[k * N];
      float * ptr_a = &A[i * K + k];
      for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        *(ptr_c+j) += *ptr_a * *(ptr_b + j);
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

Thus, my convolution code is as follows:

```cpp
void Conv2d(Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, Tensor output, int stride, int pad, int dilation, bool has_bias) {
  int C = input.shape[0], H = input.shape[1], W = input.shape[2];
  int K = weight.shape[0], R = weight.shape[2], S = weight.shape[3];
  int OH = output.shape[1], OW = output.shape[2];
  CHECK_ERROR(OH == (H + 2 * pad - dilation * (R - 1) - 1) / stride + 1, "Output height mismatch");
  CHECK_ERROR(OW == (W + 2 * pad - dilation * (S - 1) - 1) / stride + 1, "Output width mismatch");
  CHECK_ERROR(weight.shape[1] == C && (!has_bias || bias.shape[0] == K) && output.shape[0] == K, "Channel size mismatch");

  float* col = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * (C * R * S * H * W));
  im2col_cpu(input.buf, C, H, W, R, S, pad, stride, dilation, col);
  mat_mul(weight.buf, col, output.buf, K, OH * OW, R * S * C, has_bias);

  free(col);

}
```

However, it turns out that my code is **not** the same as a regular convolution using the standard **very slow** algorithm in that the output from using the matrix multiplication method **did not** match the output from using the below method.

```cpp
void Conv2d(Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, Tensor output, int stride, int pad, int dilation, bool has_bias) {
  int C = input.shape[0], H = input.shape[1], W = input.shape[2];
  int K = weight.shape[0], R = weight.shape[2], S = weight.shape[3];
  int OH = output.shape[1], OW = output.shape[2];
  CHECK_ERROR(OH == (H + 2 * pad - dilation * (R - 1) - 1) / stride + 1, "Output height mismatch");
  CHECK_ERROR(OW == (W + 2 * pad - dilation * (S - 1) - 1) / stride + 1, "Output width mismatch");
  CHECK_ERROR(weight.shape[1] == C && (!has_bias || bias.shape[0] == K) && output.shape[0] == K, "Channel size mismatch");

  for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
    for (int oh = 0; oh < OH; ++oh) {
      for (int ow = 0; ow < OW; ++ow) {
        float o = has_bias ? bias.buf[k] : 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < C; ++c) {
          for (int r = 0; r < R; ++r) {
            for (int s = 0; s < S; ++s) {
              int h = oh * stride - pad + r * dilation;
              int w = ow * stride - pad + s * dilation;
              if (h < 0 || h >= H || w < 0 || w >= W) continue;
              float i = input.buf[c * H * W + h * W + w];
              float f = weight.buf[k * C * R * S + c * R * S + r * S + s];
              o += i * f;
            }
          }
        }
        output.buf[k * OH * OW + oh * OW + ow] = o;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on why my matrix multiplication code is not working?

Comment: Unrelated: Many people find `ptr_c[j]` easier to read than  `*(ptr_c+j)` (it's also less verbose).

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I used to think that `*(ptr_c + i)` made sequential memory access faster than using brakets `ptr_c[i]` and it kind of became a habit.

Comment: They will be compiled into the same thing so they are equally fast :-)

Comment: Yup! I guess I need to work on my code readability

Comment: Off topic but... why use a brute force method such as this rather than a Fourier transform based algorithm using e.g. [`fftw3`](http://www.fftw.org/index.html#documentation)?

Comment: This is a part of a larger project where I wanted to create my own neural network and see for myself how the best algorithms optimize NN inferences. If you have any resources that describe the algorithm of fftw and how it works, I would love to learn about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I found out what the problem was. In my original code, I set the bias as

```cpp
float o = has_bias ? bias.buf[k] : 0;
```

where k represents the kth filter out of `K` filters. However, in my `mat_mul` code I naively thought that `*(ptr_c+j) += *ptr_a * *(ptr_b + j);` would add the right amount of bias to the final output.

I have changed my code to say instead:

```cpp
void mat_mul(float *A, float *B, float *C, Tensor bias, int M, int N, int K, bool has_bias) {
  # pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    int h_offset = i * N;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        C[h_offset + j] = has_bias ? bias.buf[i] : 0;
    }
  }
  
  int i, j, k;
  # pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k)
  for (i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    for (k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
      int ptr_c = i * N;
      int ptr_b = k * N;
      int ptr_a = i * K + k;
      for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        C[ptr_c+j] += A[ptr_a] * B[ptr_b + j];
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

which would allow me to add the same amount of bias as my original code.

Comment: Note that in even in correct parallel programs it is often the case that numerical outputs from parallel execution differ slightly or heavily (depending on the numerical stability of the algorithm) from the output of the sequential version. This is due to the non-commutativity of the floating-point arithmetic and possible loss of internal precision when moving data between threads.